# Tkinter TypeError: argument of type 'StringVar' is not iterable

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to write a GUI that emulates the Hangman game using Tkinter. So far I have gotten the GUI to create a label that updates based on the letters the user has guessed correctly, but the terminal still gives an error : "TypeError: argument of type 'StringVar' is not iterable". I have looked at other solutions to this error, but haven't been able to figure out how to solve the problem.

It's not done yet - but here is the code so far:

```
import randomword
# from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

playerWord: str = randomword.get_random_word()
word_guess: str = ''
guesses = ''


def returnEntry(arg=None):
    global word_guess
    global guesses
    global wordLabel
    word_guess = ''
    # dictionary = PyDictionary()

    failed = 0
    incorrect = 10
    result = myEntry.get()

    while incorrect > 0:
        if not result.isalpha():
            resultLabel.config(text="that's not a letter")

        elif len(result) != 1:
            resultLabel.config(text="that's not a letter")

        else:
            resultLabel.config(text=result)
            assert isinstance(END, object)
            myEntry.delete(0, END)

        guesses += result

        for char in playerWord:
            if char in guesses:
                # Print the letter they guessed
                word_guess += char

            elif char not in guesses:
                # Print "_" for every letter they haven't guessed
                word_guess += "_ "
                failed += 1

        if guesses[len(guesses) - 1] not in playerWord:
            resultLabel.config(text="wrong")
            incorrect -= 1

        wordLabel = Label(root, updateLabel(word_guess))
        myEntry.delete(0, END)


resultLabel = Label(root, text="")
resultLabel.pack(fill=X)


myEntry = Entry(root, width=20)
myEntry.focus()
myEntry.bind("<Return>", returnEntry)
myEntry.pack()


text = StringVar()
text.set("your word is: " + ("_ " * len(playerWord)))
wordLabel = Label(root, textvariable=text)
wordLabel.pack()


def updateLabel(word):
    text.set("your word is: " + word)
    return text


mainloop()
```

the problem occurs when I run the function on wordLabel: "wordLabel = Label(root, updateLabel(word_guess))" to reset the label. Any suggestions on how I can get the label to update to word_guess after an iteration of the while loop?

Comment: Can you include the python traceback so we can see the full error text plus failing line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is causing the error:

```
wordLabel = Label(root, updateLabel(word_guess))
```

You've overthought that. It should be simply this:

```
updateLabel(word_guess)
```

---

You also have another major error in there. This line:

```
while incorrect > 0:
```

Will cause your program to lock up. You need to change it to this:

```
if incorrect > 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wordLabel = Label(root, updateLabel(word_guess))
```

You attempt to create a new `Label` and make the global `wordLabel` refer to the new Label instead of the old one. Even if it worked properly, this would not update your GUI, since the new label is not packed.

The reason it breaks is that, although `updateLabel` changes the contents of the `StringVar` named `text` and returns it back, it is not being used as the `textvariable` of the new label. Aside from specifying the parent widget, you should use only keyword arguments for the constructor, or the argument is likely to be interpreted differently from what you expect. (I'm surprised you can call the function this way at all, frankly; I would have expected a `TypeError` at the point of the call.)

Anyway, all you need to do - since `text` is also global - is directly `.set` it to the new text. This will automatically update the appearance of `wordLabel` (modulo any tkinter stuff needed to refresh the display generally) - that's *the point of the StringVar container class* (as opposed to just using a plain string).